# how to trigger dragging of image with drag of other image using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-draggable

I am working with jquery for dragging of images.
Below is my code

```
        $( "#imgMaster" ). draggable
        ({ 
            axis: "y", 
            containment:[0,170,0,430],  
            start: function(event, ui)
                            {
                                $("#imgFrontLeft").trigger('draggable');
                            }

        });

        $( "#imgFrontLeft" ). draggable
        ({ 
            axis: "y" ,
            containment:[0,162,0,290],
        });
```

My requirement is that, on drag of #imgMaster, #imgFrontLeft must be dragged. 
Both the images are dragged independently. 
Kindly help me with , how could i meet my requirement.

Comment: Is their any working demo?

Comment: Working Demo as in ? jsFiddle ??

Comment: If it can or copy your code in the question you asked.

Comment: Sorry Rohan but i am still not getting what exactly are u looking for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LEneV/1/) link this will help you to get the answer for synchronizing two images for dragging.
you can use this

```
 $("#imgFrontLeft").css('left',ui.position.left); 
 $("#imgFrontLeft").css('top',ui.position.top);
```

in your code to drag the images, i hope this will help you more.